# Grep Exported-Packages from a MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, bash, grep, osgi

I need help to grep the exported packages from an OSGi MANIFEST.MF file. 
For example, from the following file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyBundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: mybundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.6.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3.1"
Export-Package: foo.bar.bla,
 foo.bar.blo,
 foo.bor.ble,
 foo.bor.bli
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-Activator: foo.bar.bla.Activator
```

I need to get:

```
foo.bar.bla
foo.bar.blo
foo.bor.ble
foo.bor.bli
```

We must have in mind that the following tag after the last package could be Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironmen or Bundle-Activator, or any other.

**EDIT**:
With:

```
cat MANIFEST.MF | awk '/Export-Package:(.*)/ {print $2; flag=1} flag=1 && /:/ {flag=0;next } flag=1 {print}' | sed 's/,//g'
```

I'm getting:

```
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3.1"
foo.bar.bla
 foo.bar.blo
 foo.bor.ble
 foo.bor.bli
```

It shouldn't retrieve org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3.1"

Comment: do let us know what you tried

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for questions and answers. Do you have a question that you want to ask?

Comment: The question is how do I do what I've explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use [bnd](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd).

- [install bnd](http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/120-install.html)
- Execute `bnd select --header Export-Package my.jar`

And all the edge cases are handled for you.

---

Old answer for people interested in "using the command line" aspect of the question.

This is not a job for Grep as `grep` is a line-by-line sort of thing, this is a job for `awk` or `sed`!

```
echo "Export-Package: foo.bar.bla,
    foo.bar.blo,
    foo.bor.ble,
    foo.bor.bli
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
" | cat MANIFEST.MF | awk '/Export-Package:(.*)/ {print $2; flag=1; next} flag && /:/ {flag=0;next} flag {print}' | sed 's/,//g'
```

- `/Export-Package:(.*)/` Find the line "Export-Package" and capture what ever is after ":".
- `{print $2; flag=1; next}` Print out the captured group and set a flag to true. Skip the rest of the rule for this line
- `flag && /:/` When the flag is set, and the line contains ":"
- `{flag=0;next }` Set the flat to false and skip the rest of the rules for this line
- `flag` If the flag is true
- `{print}` Print out the line.

However this does not cover  edge cases such as word wraps (thanks [Neil Bartlett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318921/neil-bartlett)), while we could make the awk program more complex this is a waste of time when someone else has created an application to do just that (thanks [BJ Hargrave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448551/bj-hargrave)).

Comment: Unfortunately not because according to the JAR File Specification, the lines of a MANIFEST.MF must be wrapped at 72 bytes, and they continue on the next line with a two-space indent. This can split up the package name. So any search job would have to be programmed to understand this format and join the lines back together.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how does awk work. The result of the command above isn't exactly what I need.

Comment: @mlk - It is not. The problem is that it will also return org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3.1", which isn't an exported package.

Comment: I've added the result of the command at the end of my question. Take a look at the EDIT.

Comment: Updated. Does not cover the case mentioned by @NeilBartlett

Comment: Line continuation in the manifest is just a single space indent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value_pairs_and_Sections

Comment: Also "bnd select --header Export-Package my.jar" will dump out the Export-Package statement from my.jar's manifest.

Comment: @BJHargrave Awesome, what package is bnd part of? I've never heard of it before?

Comment: bnd is the OSGi development tool. See https://github.com/bndtools/bnd. I have installed bnd as a command. See http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/120-install.html.